# nagios & nagiosgrapher & check_disk -A

Tags: graph, nagios

I check most Host(group)s with `check_disk -A ...`.
Because of the fact that i have many machines with many different mounted filesystem, i do not want to make extra checks for every mounted drive.

Now with nagiosgrapher i thought, i have a section for every mountpoint that could be available on a machine (/, /home, /srv, /srv/repos, ...), pull the values out of the performance data and print stuff from this mountpoint in a separate page - something like this:

```
# for /
define ngraph{
    service_name            disk
    graph_perf_regex        \/=(\d+)MB;
    graph_value             root_abs_used
    graph_units             MB
    graph_legend            / used (MB)
    rrd_plottype            AREA
    rrd_color               ff0000
    page                    /
}

# for /home
define ngraph{
    service_name            disk
    graph_perf_regex        \/home=(\d+)MB;
    graph_value             home_abs_used
    graph_units             MB
    graph_legend            /home used (MB)
    rrd_plottype            AREA
    rrd_color               ff0000
    page                    /home
}

# for /srv
define ngraph{ ... }
```

But nagiosgrapher throws away data which does not match **all** `graph_perf_regex` for one service.

So the question is: Is there a way to tell nagiosghrapher to ignore not-matching `graph_perf_regex` or something like that. Or is there any other way to get this or similar thing working which i can't see?

Question clear? I hope so ...

Thanks a lot!

P.S.: I really do not want to define nagios checks for every single mountpoint, nonono ... don't want to do that ... :)